# Retrieve JSON data and keeping record of specific value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build a simple code where I fetch some JSON data (weather information) and log the temperature to the console. HEre is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Weather Application</title>
  </head>

<body>    
<script>
var cityName = prompt("Please enter city name", "London");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&appid=65a3719d36e2d698392212cd888b5ccf', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data => {
      console.log(main.temp)
    }
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}
request.send()    
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I get the prompt to enter the city name and the value is saved to the variable properly. However, my console is not logging the temperature.

Here is a sample of the JSON response:

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":300,
         "main":"Drizzle",
         "description":"light intensity drizzle",
         "icon":"09d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{  
      "temp":280.32,
      "pressure":1012,
      "humidity":81,
      "temp_min":279.15,
      "temp_max":281.15
   },
   "visibility":10000,
   "wind":{  
      "speed":4.1,
      "deg":80
   },
   "clouds":{  
      "all":90
   },
   "dt":1485789600,
   "sys":{  
      "type":1,
      "id":5091,
      "message":0.0103,
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1485762037,
      "sunset":1485794875
   },
   "id":2643743,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have already searched for several code examples on how to do it.

I would like to have the console logging the temperature. 
Also, does anyone knows how to convert the temperature from Kelvin to Celsius?

Comment: Where is main defined?

Comment: Idk this statement: `data => {
      console.log(main.temp)
    }` what its supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var cityName = prompt("Please enter city name", "London");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=65a3719d36e2d698392212cd888b5ccf`, true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // kelvin to celsius formula is celsius = Kelvin - 273.15
      console.log(`${data.main.temp - 273.15}C`)

  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}
request.send()    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property `temp` on the base object - it is in the nested `data` object:

```
console.log(data.main.temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var cityName = prompt("Please enter city name", "London");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&appid=65a3719d36e2d698392212cd888b5ccf', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      ((main)=>{
          console.log(main.temp)
      })(data.main)
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}
request.send()    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var cityName = prompt("Please enter city name", "London");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&appid=65a3719d36e2d698392212cd888b5ccf', true)
request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here 
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let temperature = data.main.temp - 273.15;
        console.log(temperature);
    } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}
request.send()    
</script>
```